# catalog product url rewrite

Tags: catalog, url-rewrite, reindex

my product catalog url rewrite, is being developed for several days. How can I Optimiz this process in a short time, for about 15,000 products?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the index from your admin panel? I would say that your indexer process has probably failed, the ui is saying it is still processing as it never finished and got marked as complete.

Try using magentos cli indexer tool  instead of the ui. E.g in path/to/magento/shell/ run:

```
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
```

You will have better visibility to what's actually happening, if the process dies you will see. If your index really is running for days for 15000 products then I think you have other problems.